# What is the difference between getProviders() and getAllProviders() methods (Android)

Tags: android, geolocation, location

The documentation says - 
getAllProviders ()
Returns a list of the names of all known location providers.

getProviders (boolean)
Returns a list of the names of location providers.

What actually is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay got the Answer !

getproviders() returns list of only "enabled" location providers.